# iOS Safari address bar suggests URL's I haven't visited

Tags: ios, malware, mobile-safari, safari-extensions

Over the last couple of months I've noticed that when I start typing in the address/search bar in Safari on my iPhone it will sometimes auto-complete with websites that I haven't visited. But Search Engine Suggestions and Safari Suggestions are turned off. Moreover, the sites are always very specific rather than constantly adapting to what is typed in. They are seemingly legitimate sites (things like comparison websites) and often seem related to stuff I have looked at previously.

I have two content blockers installed (AdGuard and BlockBear) plus the built in popup blocker turned on. AdGuard also has a Safari extension component but is not enabled as I've seen no benefit over using it as a content blocker only. So as far as I am aware neither AdGuard nor BlockBear should even be capable of doing this even in the event they had gone rogue.

I had suspected a certain games site might be responsible but I have been using the incognito mode to access it recently and the problem persists. I've been clearing the history regularly which removes the URL's but new ones always come back eventually

There should be no one else with access to my devices to explain this behaviour. I'm at a loss to find the culprit and beginning to think I could have some kind of malware.

I'm on iOS 15.4.1

Comment: Did you clean site data in settings/safari/advanced/site data  ? It is quite useful and may give some free space also. Be also sure to not be connected to a Google account.

Comment: If already clears site data when I clear the history. I do have a Google account linked (for syncing contacts) but I can’t see any way it would be relevant

Comment: Because if you are connected to your Google account, it will retain all the search you are doing and may be the site you go from Google pages.

Comment: No this is nothing to do with search history, this is in the address bar of a new empty tab and I am signed out of all Google sites within Safari. Today it popped up with some cycling magazine I had never even heard of let alone searched for